# In the proof that $DSPACE(S)\subseteq DTIME(2^{O(S)})$, why precisely do we require that $S=\Omega(\log n)$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have read and understood various proofs, but have not been able to understand precisely why we require $S=\Omega(\log n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We believe that $DSPACE(X) \subseteq DTIME(X)$ is false. As a consequence, $X$ must be chosen so that $X \neq 2^{O(X)}$. Additionally, considering $DSPACE(X) \subseteq DTIME(Y)$ we want $ Y = 2^{O(X)}$ to allow the Turing machine requiring $X$ space to halt on all of its inputs: this is because the number of configurations is $O(2^{O(X)})$ and any accepting computation must halt within $O(2^{O(X)})$ steps, i.e. this is $2^{O(X)}$ if $X = \Omega(\lg n)$. Moreover, the function $X$ must be space constructible as well, and $\lg n$ is space constructible. This is also consistent with the definition of the complexity classes $L$ and $P$. The former is the class of the languages (or problems) requiring at most $O(\lg n)$ space, the latter the class of languages requiring at most polynomial time. The relationship $L \subset P$ holds because a Turing machine requiring at most logarithmic space can use at most linear time, so polynomial time.